# Add decorator to method from library class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class that I cannot change (it comes from a library), which may look like

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def bar(self, x):
        return x
```

And I want to add a decorator to the `bar` method in `Test`, like the following, for instance:

```py
from functools import wraps

def some_decorator(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return "<b>" + fn(*args, **kwargs) + "</b>"
    return wrapped
```

By "adding" the decorator I mean to have a way to generate objects that have the `bar` method wrapped in `some_decorator`.

However, I cannot change the code in `Test`, which makes my problem harder. Is there an easy way to add a decorator in a method from a class that I cannot change in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to modify the original class definition then you can achieve this with with simple inheritance itself instead of using decorators..

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def bar(self, x):
        print("In base bar..")
        return x

class DerivedTest(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def bar(self,x):
        print("In derive's bar..")
        super().bar(x)
```

Now say when you execute:

```
dt=DerivedTest()
dt.bar(10)
```

The output will be

```
In derive's bar..
In base bar..
```

You can put whatever wrapper code you were intending to before and after the super() call..

Comment: You can also use the decorator; just do something like `bar = decorator(Test.bar)` instead of a `def` statement. (I'm not sure how, if at all, you can use `super` instead of `Test`.)

Answer (score 4):

As you probably know the decorator is just a function which takes a function as an argument and returns a new function, thus you can do following nasty-hacky monkeypatching:

```
import your_library
your_library.Test.your_function = your_decorator(your_library.Test.your_function)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it nasty-hacky as this is the only way to decorate a function if `@deco` syntax didn't exist.

Comment: wouldnt this modify the class definition globally??

Comment: @Asocia Applying the decorator isn't the hack; patching the existing class is.

Comment: @chepner I don't see any difference between decorating an outside function directly or a method of an outside class by reaching it via dot notation so there is no hack for me :D

Comment: The hack has nothing to do with the decorator. The issue is replacing a class attribute without necessarily knowing if the thing you are replacing it with meshes with the rest of the class.

Comment: @chepner Oh, I got you know.